# How to remove scrolling from iframe (have tried "overflow: hidden" and "scrolling: no")?

Tags: html, wordpress, iframe, scroll, vertical-scrolling

Within a wordpress shapely-theme widget: am embedding iframes, have tried css: iframe {overflow:hidden} and have checked that the attribute 'scrolling:"no" ' is present in the tags. Still, vertical scrollbar on all iframes. Even tried a loop in javascript that added the attribute to the iframes (if wordpress for some reason gets rid of them), still didn't help.

Any ideas how to get rid of the scrollbars?

Comment: Did you try the combination of those two?

Comment: Yes - tried both in place at the same time, and then one at a time.

Comment: Give it another try with a combination of `overflow: hidden;`, `scrolling: no`, and specific `width` and `height` on `iframe` tag (prefered) or CSS selector.

Comment: Thank you - but this is what the tag looks like - width and height are already there, have tried changing the values if that would help, but no: <iframe  style="margin-top:10px" src="source-here" height="102px" width="400px" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was due to something in wordpress or the shapely-template - I noticed how after saving, it always removed the scrolling-attribute from the iframe-tag, although it always was there when I copied it in or edited it before saving.

So had to retreat to custom HTML-widget in the end of the document, with a timeouted function that added the attribute "scrolling: no" to all iframes after the page is rendered. A really flimsy workaround, so might go into changing the template and trying another one. Also to see if it's a wordpress thing.

```
setTimeout(function(){

var epis = document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")
for (var i = 0; i < epis.length; i++){epis[i].setAttribute("scrolling", "no")}

}, 2000)
```